# How can we differentiate these patterns by some index?

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, geospatial, image-recognition, pattern-recognition

[Please see 3 assumed patterns here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXJSd.jpg)

Q1:list index to determine whether the pattern is uniformly distributed or clustered?

Q2: given your index, how to determine whether or not it is clustered if I only have one analyzed pattern?(i.e. is there threshold for comparison)

Q3: how to differentiate (2) and (3),i.e. how many clusters? How compact they are?

PS:I just show the case in 2D, but the index should be also applicable in higher dimensional cases.

Comment: Cool - which exam is this?

Comment: It's a question derived from my research...